# Possible security issues in a trading app (Django)

Tags: django, security, database-design

Being not a security expert I hope you can clarify something for me.

I'm building an app where Users can "trade" virtual goods. I'm building it with Django just in case your interested.

A sample scenario:
**Alice** (`UserID=1`) has **good-A** with a certain value (x). Where **good-A** is basically a database entry in the "`tradable items`" DB with the properties (`ID, Name, Desc, Value, Owner`). The owner of **good-A** is **Alice**. Now if **Alice** wants to give **good-A** to **Bob** (`UserID=2`) she changes the "`Owner`" property of **good-A** to Bob's `UserID=2`.

This means. To get the total value of all items Alice posesses I make a db query asking "`accumulate the Value values of all items in the tradable items database having the Owner=1`"

So all goods of all users are stored in one database. Could there be a security problem that  (evil) users can change the Owner property of a tradable item, that does not belong to them, to be their own item?

I know it depends on the particular implementation but maybe you see a flaw in this plan in general...

So... is this a good way to implement such a scenario? Or do you have any better ideas?

Answer (score 2):

From a technical perspective, plug every leak.  Deny by default.

From a business risk perspective, assume your technical efforts are only 99% effective and take steps to mitigate.

1) Log every trade.  If a security hole ever opens, so long as you still have your log you can go back and undo whatever damage was done.  Most fraud will be exploiting front end loopholes.

2) Take periodic db backups.  If a security hole opens, you could also loose your db log.  You'll want backups that go back a long way

3) Email users every time they acquire/transfer items.  BCC yourself -- this creates 2 redundant copies of the trade log (one in email, one in the db) on two different systems -- now they have to hack your email server too to get away with fraud.  If 1 fails, you might be able to recover from this.  It also lets your users find problems for you.

4) For high value transactions, especially converting to cash, add human authorization.  Let them do batch transactions twice a day -- but humans know something is wrong when transfers are usually in the 20-30 per hour range and are suddenly 5000 -- computers don't.  Humans are much better at heuristics than computers, use them to once over and make sure nothing fishy is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that it does depend completely on your implementation. The security issue is determined by how you actually let a user change ownership of an item. If you have a simple form that shows you all the items a user owns, and they pick one and change the owner, the page will reload and they no longer have that item anymore to modify. It is also a manner of your queries. If UserA request to change the ownership of ItemA but they are not the owner, you fail that request.

So really, there is no way for the client side to change Items that do not belong to them as long as you are only showing them Items they own, and only succeeding a change of ownership on Items they originally own.

*Edit*

And example of a situation where it would be a security issue, is where you expose a REST api that clients can communicate with via javascript, and you allow them to freely modify any Item ID they specify in their PUT request data.